# How do I iterate over a dataframe with non-integer values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to python and am trying to to iterate a dataframe with values from two dataframes.

For example: Dataframe A(dfA) looks like this and gives me the values that I need to iterate with.

**NP**
1:123
5:657
4:789

Dataframe B(dfB) looks like this

[DataframeB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpDkZ.png)

From the values in Dataframe A I want to iterate over columns in Dataframe B and if the value matches then copy the entire column to Dataframe C (dfC). I have 1500 columns and hence cannot do this manually.

I am currently using this code to accomplish this with no luck.

```
for ip in dfA.values: 
    dfC[dfA.iloc[ip]]= dfB[dfA.iloc[ip]]
```

This code gives the following error: 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1:2234'

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) (that locates by integer) instead of [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) (that locates by value/label)

But how about the following?

```
for ip in dfA.values: 
    if ip in dfB:
        dfC[ip]= dfB[ip]
```

I recommend to read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) tutorial on how to access and modify rows and columns in pandas.